# VBA for each loop locked when I revert revisions

Tags: vba, foreach, ms-word, revision-history

I want to get both the revised and original text from a document. I do it this way:

```
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileName)

For each sent in wrdDoc.Sentences

    if sent.Revisions.Count >=0 then
        after=sent.text
        sent.Revisions.RejectAll 
        before=sent.text
        SaveRev(before,after)
    End if

next
```

Now that would be fine, except that malformed sentences like

> This is one sentence.This is another.

Will get parsed in a weird way. First, there will be this one: "**This is one sentence.**", then this one with both "**This is one sentence.This is another.**"

What happens when there are revisions there? The first iteration will revert revisions on the first sentence, then the second iteration will not 'see' that revised portion.

Bottom line is, the first iteration will get both versions of the first sentence, and the second iteration will get only the original version of the first sentence (while getting both versions from the second sentence).

Let me clarify:

Let's say I had the original

> We started with this sentence.And this sentence.

And it was revised to

> We ended with this sentence.And this other sentence.

First iteration will result in

> Before: We started with this sentence.
>
> After: We ended with this sentence.

But second iteration will have

> Before: We ended with this sentence.And this sentence.
>
> After: We ended with this sentence.And this other sentence.

Well, what I did was alter the logic, undoing the revision reversion:

```
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileName)

For each sent in wrdDoc.Sentences

    if sent.Revisions.Count >=0 then
        wrdDoc.Undo
        after=sent.text
        sent.Revisions.RejectAll 
        before=sent.text
        SaveRev(before,after)
    End if

next
```

I like this because I end up with an unaltered document (except for the last sentence).

The thing is, doing this puts the macro in an infinite loop at one specific sentence.

I have no idea of the mechanics of the for each, I have no clue what is causing it to hang. Obviously altering the collection is messing up the loop, but I don't understand why.

I could loop for i=0 to wrdDoc.Sentences.Count, but I think that will make me skip sentences for the same reasons I'm repeating one now, and I cannot risk it (even if I test OK, I have to be sure it will never happen).

So the question is (are):

1. Can any one help me figuring out why it's locking on a sentence,
2. Is there a better way of doing this?
3. How can I solve it while making sure not to skip sentences.

Thank you very much!

PS: I can provide sample documents, let me know if it's needed (maybe what I'm doing wrong is already clear to someone, and I'd have to make the samples as I cannot share the documents I'm working on).

--EDIT--

Ok so this is where it's hanging, only on the 32nd file.

It doesn't hang on a sentence, it actually does a few at the start of the document, then goes back to the beginning.

I previously encountered the same error, but it looped in a single sentence, and didn't go back to the beginning. I think it's the same issue. I'll try to reproduce original and revised versions here.

Originalversion

```
MAIN TITLE

Measurement of some variable

1   REQUIRED TOOLS

1.1 Special tools

NOTe:

Some note about the procedure (unaltered by revision)

Equipment name (carrier returned line)
(english) assemply with Equipment PN
Kit

Equipment name (carrier returned line)
(english) assemply with (Another) Equipment PN
Kit

Document continues...
```

There are 2 equipment entries before it restarts the loop.

Revision consisted of inserting the document number, some First Letter of the Word caps, and changing the order between Equipment PN and "Kit".

Revised version

```
ducument number
MAIN TITLE

Measurement of Some Variable

1   REQUIRED TOOLS

1.1 Special Tools

NOTe:

Some note about the procedure (unaltered by revision)

Equipment name (carrier returned line)
(english) assemply with kit
Equipment PN


Equipment name (carrier returned line)
(english) assemply with kit
(Another) Equipment PN


Document continues...
```

Recorded original/revison pairs were:

Original..................................Revised

{Empty}...................................Document number

Measurement of some variable..............Measurement of Some Variable

Special tools............................Special Tools

(english) assemply with..................(english) assemply with kit

(english) assemply with..................(english) assemply with kit

Then it starts again, recording the same entries until I break.
I don't see the sentences overlapping I talked about, but there was a line break insertion on the revision.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it always hang on the same sentence? If yes, what sentence is that?

Comment: I have to reach my workstation as the files do not leave the client. I'll try on other files to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: "I like this because I end up with an unaltered document (except for the last sentence).": FYI to make it undo the last sentence simply move `wrdDoc.Undo` to be beneath `before=sent.text`

Comment: Enumerable objects should not be altered during the enumeration or bad things tm can happen. My guess is that the revision/undo process, combined with the wonky sentence, is causing the Sentences enumerable to change. You should prepare your own collection first, to see if that makes a difference. Simply try `Set sents = New Collection: For Each sent in wrdDoc.Sentences: sents.Add sent: Next` then use `sents` for your main For Each loop.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey Your answer solved my problem. If you want to post it, I'll accept it.

Comment: @RSinohara thanks, glad it was sorted. Things like this are hard to pin down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerable objects should not be altered during the enumeration or bad things can happen (what depends on the type of collection).

My guess is that the revision/undo process, combined with the wonky sentence, is causing the Sentences enumerable to change.

You should prepare your own collection first, to see if that makes a difference. Simply try `Set sents = New Collection: For Each sent in wrdDoc.Sentences: sents.Add sent: Next` then use sents for your main For Each loop.